# Getting push reject when trying to push to a remote branch

Tags: git, github, merge, push, branch

After getting changes from a different branch using rebase when, I'm trying push the new changes to a remote private branch I'm getting the following message

> Push of the current branch XXXX was rejected.
>       Remotes changes needs to be merged before pushing.
>       In this case **merge is highly recommended,** because there are non pushed 
>       merge commits. Rebasing them can lead to problems.

Can you please explain more about this problem?
If I'm using my own personal branch can I force push to it without a worry?

[image]

Comment: It seems that branch you are pushing is not fast forward wrt destination one. So, you may run `git push -f ...` if you indeed want to rewrite it.

Comment: It sounds like your GitHub is configured to be non rebase-friendly.  As the above comment says, you can do `git push --force` in this case.   Note that if this branch is your own private one, then there is nothing wrong with doing a force push.